# What encryption is used by default SecureSocial for SecureSocialPasswordHasher?

Tags: python, encryption, playframework, passwords, securesocial

I've got a passwords on a datastore that were hashed using the method `SecureSocialPasswordHasher.passwordHash` from the package `securesocial.utils.SecureSocialPasswordHasher` of `SecureSocial`, and I have to validate them through Python.

Therefore, the use of `SecureSocial` (or the whole Play Framework) is out of the question. The question is: What does it use for hashing when calling that method? From the documentation it seems it is `Bcrypt`, but it wasn't clear enough for me to be sure.

---------EDIT---------

I've been told on `SecureSocial` forums that indeed it uses `Bcrypt` with work factor 10 default. However it doens't reflect what I see on the datastore.

There are 2 columns there, one for salt, and another one fro the hashed password. Neither of them have the `Bcrypt` header (such as `$2a$10$`). Also, the salt size is only 11 characters long, and the hashed password is only 22 characters long (and no signs of having the salt inside the string).

Comment: Work factor 10 and 10 rounds are not the same thing. The number of rounds is exponential in the work factor.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. In my mind it was right, but wrote the wrong term. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the default for hashing passwords on `SecureSocial` is indeed `Bcrypt`.

The default implementation for it's hash method is:

```
  def hash(plainPassword: String): PasswordInfo = {
        PasswordInfo(id, BCrypt.hashpw(plainPassword, BCrypt.gensalt(logRounds)))
  }
```

This applies to the latest version of `SecureSocial`.

On my specific problem, the main issue was that I was not communicated that the code I was dealing with was using an older version of `SecureSocial`, and that the has method was overriden.